# Why are my switch cases being skipped and default being printed?

Tags: c++

I have written this C++ code in an attempt to simulate a vending machine. 
Whenever the user's selection is entered, a number 1-5 each assigned a case in the switch statement, none of the cases execute: the program does not recognize the valid input, and will only print out the default case statement. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int choice;
    double dollars;

    cout << "==============================================================\n";
    cout << "*                                                            *\n";
    cout << "*              VENDING MACHINE SIMULATOR                     *\n";
    cout << "*                                                            *\n";
    cout << "==============================================================\n";

    cout << "Your Choices Are:\n";

    cout << "1) Coke     - $1.75\n";
    cout << "2) Pepsi    - $2.25\n";
    cout << "3) Sprite   - $1.25\n";
    cout << "4) 7-up     - $1.15\n";
    cout << "5) Water    - $2.20\n";

    // Ask for user's selection.

    cout << "What would you like to purchase today?\n";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
            case '1': 
            {
                    cout << "How many dollar bills will you use?\n";
                    cin >> dollars;
                    {
                            if (dollars > 1.75)
                            {
                                    cout << "You purchased: Coke\n";
                                    cout << "Your change is: $"<< (dollars - 1.75);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    cout << "You do not have enough money for this purchase. Goodbye!\n";
                            }
                    }
            }
                      break;
            case '2':
            {
                    cout << "How many dollar bills will you use?\n";
                    cin >> dollars;
                    {
                            if (dollars > 2.25)
                            {
                                    cout << "You purchased: Pepsi\n";
                                    cout << "Your change is: $"<< (dollars - 1.75);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    cout << "You do not have enough money for this purchase. Goodbye!\n";
                            }
                    }
            }
            case '3': 
            {
                    cout << "How many dollar bills will you use?\n";
                    cin >> dollars;
                    {
                            if (dollars > 1.25)
                            {
                                    cout << "You purchased: Sprite\n";
                                    cout << "Your change is: $"<< (dollars - 1.25);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    cout << "You do not have enough money for this purchase. Goodbye!\n";
                            }
                    }
            }
                      break;
            case '4': 
            {
                    cout << "How many dollar bills will you use?\n";
                    cin >> dollars;
                    {
                            if (dollars > 1.15)
                            {
                                    cout << "You purchased: 7-up\n";
                                    cout << "Your change is: $"<< (dollars - 1.15);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    cout << "You do not have enough money for this purchase. Goodbye!\n";
                            }
                    }
            }
                      break;
            case '5': 
            {
                    cout << "How many dollar bills will you use?\n";
                    cin >> dollars;
                    {
                            if (dollars > 2.20)
                            {
                                    cout << "You purchased: Water\n";
                                    cout << "Your change is: $"<< (dollars - 2.20);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    cout << "You do not have enough money for this purchase. Goodbye!\n";
                            }
                    }
            }

                      break;
            default: cout << "Your choice is INVALID. Goodbye!\n"; 
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `choice`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Hopefully, it's `char` and not `int` ...

Comment: It is an integer. My apologies, I missed that part in the code, but it is there now.

Comment: The curtain has been lifted and in fact `'1'` instead of `1` in the `case` statements is the problem.

Comment: For the future, make sure debugging questions include a [mcve]. You can [edit] this one to improve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drop the single quotes used in the `case` statements.

Change

```
 case '1':
```

to

```
case 1:
```

Similarly for others.

`'1'` is a character constant while `1` is the integer constant. When ASCII encoding is used, `'1'` evaluates to the number `49`, which clearly is not equal to the number `1`. Hence, that `case:` branch is not executed when you enter `1` as your input.

Comment: That's a good guess ... but it's *ONLY* a guess, until the OP tells us the type for "choice".  You should have asked.  You should also explain the difference between integer "1" and character "1".

Comment: @xmaddiemuffin: important question - do you understand *why* it worked?  Or that you could have used *EITHER* "int" *OR* "char", as long as type "choice" matched the type in your switch/case block?

Comment: Now that it has been explained to me, yes I do understand it. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 3):

`'1'` is a character.  When you input `1` into an integer it is stored as `1` not `'1'`.  You need to change all the cases of `'x'` to `x`.

The reason you do not get any errors about this is that `'1'` can be implicitly converted to an `int` and it has a value of the implementations character encoding.  If it was ASCII the it would be `49`

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

Change `int choice` to `char choice`

Or

Change `case '1':` to `case 1:`.

Answer (score 1):

'break' statement is missing for Case 2 and change case '1': to case 1.

Comment: Good catch about the missing "break" - thank you for pointing it out!